# Is getting two residence card possible from different countries?

Tags: germany, resident-permit, poland

I have a quite complex situation. I have a temporary residence card (Blue card) as a dependant of my husband from Poland. I got a job offer from Germany and planning to apply for a German D type visa. Is my residence card from Poland going to be cancelled or is it valid until the expiration date?
What happens if my husband also applies for a residence card as a dependant of me from Germany? He will continue to work in Poland and I will be working from Germany. Can we have two residence cards? Because we will be working remotely and will have to stay in Poland or Germany for more than 3 months.